# Using `lsqnonlin` with vector inputs

Tags: matlab, vector, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, function-handle

I have a question about using the [`lsqnonlin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html) function.

In my case I have two functions:

```
f_1=@(t,x)sin(t+x.^2);
f_2=@(t,x)cos(x.^2)+3.*t.^2;
f = {f_1, f_2};
```

I want to find the values of the arguments `t` and `x` which would result in the least square error, defined as: `f_1(t,x)^2+f_2(t,x)^2`. In other words, *argmin for LSE*.

My code is as follow with initial guess `[1,2]`:

```
lsqnonlin(f,[1,2])
```

And I'm getting the error:

> ```
> Error in lsqnonlin (line 196)
>         initVals.F = feval(funfcn{3},xCurrent,varargin{:});
> Caused by:
> Failure in initial objective function evaluation. LSQNONLIN cannot continue.
> ```

`lsqnonlin` can be used for vector function and vector input according to the documentation. I wonder how to prepare corresponding codes for it. Could anyone suggest the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because `lsqnonlin` expects a scalar function handle that maps a **vector to a vector**, whereas you specify a cell array of function handles. To fix this, instead of a vector of functions outputting one scalar each, you need to rewrite it into a single function that accepts a **vector** of inputs and also outputs a **vector**:

```
f = @(xt)[sin(xt(2)+xt(1).^2), cos(xt(1).^2)+3.*xt(2).^2];    
% xt = [x,t]   
% f = [f_1(xt), f_2(xt)]
```

so `f` and `xt` are both vectors of 2 elements.

Then, the solver works:

```
lsqnonlin(f,[1,2])

ans =

    1.6144    0.5354
```